# How to add a value in register bh to ecx in NASM assembler?

Tags: assembly, nasm

Suppose I have a number in bh, how do I add it to ecx? I cannot just

```
add ecx, bh
```

since it will cause an error:

```
invalid combination of opcode and operands
```

because ecx is a 32 bit register and bh is an 8 bit register.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add values of different sizes (the CPU doesn't support it). Instead, try something like this:

```
    movzx ebx,bl        ;Zero-extend BL
    add ecx,ebx
```

Note: For signed numbers you can also use `movsx` to sign-extend.

Answer (score 3):

If it's ok to modify ebx, then for unsigned add:

```
    movzx   ebx,bh
    add     ecx,ebx
```

and for signed add:

```
    movsx   ebx,bh
    add     ecx,ebx
```

if it's not ok to modify ebx, then for unsigned add:

```
    add     cl,bh
    jnc     nocarry0
    add     ecx,0100h
nocarry0:
```

or just use the first two examples preceded by push ebx, and followed by pop ebx.

Comment: You're correct. I thought I had already fixed this. It's fixed now. I also lost a comment where I asked if the original add was supposed to be add ch,bh.

Comment: I think the last code snippet is best because you cannot assume that [e]bx can be modified. You could although push/pop ebx if necessary. Since that way you avoid a branch, it may very well be as fast.

Comment: why not extend directly from bh to ebx?

Answer (score 0):

unsigned add:

```
add cl,bh
adc ecx,0100h
```